# Monitoring a folder for new files in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the best way to go about monitoring a folder to see when an image file has been added to it? Files are added approximately once a minute and the naming goes like this... image0001.jpg, image0002.jpg, image0003.jpg etc. I need to know when a file has been written to the folder so that my app can access and use it.

Answer (score 14):

Look into [directory change notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

As per previously mentioned, the directory change notifications is what you want.

I have looked into them as well, and the caveat I have seen is that windows will fire off the notification when the file starts to be written to the folder.  If the file is large enough then you will receive the notification before the file has finished being written.

Check out [this google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=filesystemwatcher+large+files&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for various solutions for waiting until the file is completely written

**Edit**: I just saw that the question was tagged with c++, and I linked to a .Net search.  Although what I provided may not  be the correct language, I would think that you will still have the same issues on Windows no matter what system you are coding with.

Answer (score 1):

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) should be able to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change notifactions may cause some overhead, if you've NTFS, consider [NTFS change journals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a polling method to monitor the folder. The loop will execute every 5 seconds, for example.

This method returns a list of new files:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
string path = @"C:\test\"; // whatever the path is

public List<string> GetNewFiles(string path)
    {
        // store all the filenames (only .jpg files) in a list
        List<string> currentFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");

        if ( currentFiles.Count() > files.Count() )
        {
            count = newFiles.Length - files.Length;
            List<string> newFiles = new List<string>();

            foreach ( string file in currentFiles )
            {
                if ( !files.Contains(file) )
                {
                    newFiles.Add(file);
                }
             }
         }
         files = currentFiles;
         return newFiles;
    }
```

This is the method that will poll every 5 seconds and call the previous method.

```
public void MonitorFolder()
{
    while (true)
    {
        List<string> newFiles = GetNewFiles(path);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // 5000 milliseconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Synch.variant [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
2. Asynch.variant [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This was the top google result for my search so I'll add this as an answer.

If you're using Qt, there's [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html). I didn't know this existed and we happened to be using Qt, so I wasted more than a few hours using [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications) to rewrite what was readily available to me until a colleague showed me the light.

Good learning experience though.

Answer (score -1):

[inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) might be your thing

Comment: Inotify is Linux-only, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm. I was under the impression that the librarys were ported to different platforms.